# None of internet connections possible

Tags: networking, internet, broadcom, interface, adapter

After a difficult process resizing my root partition, messing up and reparing boot partition, none of the internet connection methods work. My drivers where installed before and dont seem to be gone. I have an integrated Broadcom adapter and Tplink, not working as well as usb tethering wich was saving me some times in similar situations after fresh installs. lsmod | grep wifi, nmcli dev wifi list, lspci | grep Wireless are empty. iwconfig shows nothing relevant to. For mobile device or usb-tethering no entrys, when mobile gets connected doenst shows up too. Noticed that older linux kernels are most likely gone and chrooting into root from Live usb didnt managed any installs or updates when i was mounting unmounting playing with partitions.

sudo lshw -C network shows *-network

```
description: Network Controller
product BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:24:00.0
version: 00
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciecpress BUS_master CAP_list
configuration: DRIVER=bcma-pci-bridge LATENCY=0
resources: irq:19 memory:d4400000-d4403fff.
```

if someone has an understanding of what is going on please provide some information to fix.

Comment: You've provided no OS & release details; and if you deleted files installed on your file-system but not via the package manager tools; database will show they are installed even if files are not (ie. your package database no longer represents what exists on your file-system due to file deletes being used and not package removal). Please be precise in what you did & start with your OS & release details.

Comment: I was trying to mount in a new root Partition from the live Usb with mounting /proc /dev /run, chrooting and syncing. dont remember what the chroot was for, no files where deleted manually. After that i gave up mounting in a new root partition and deleted the boot partition wich was the last partition in the table keeping me from resizing my used Root partition. After that i have created a new boot partition and set all to work with boot-repair. The OS is Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, Kernel: Linux 5.4.0-47-generic. Thanks for the response

Comment: Bluetooth dont works too. like Wifi it cant even be enabled